# How to install pip with python 2.6 on Windows

Tags: pip, python-2.6

Im attempting to install pip with python 2.6 on my dev machine to try to match a deployment environment that also uses python 2.6.

Python 2.6 is installed OK. I've tried installing pip using get-pip.py as outlined here https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/ with the version of the get-pip.py script from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/2.6/get-pip.py

However it fails with the following:

```
C:\users\me> python get-pip.py
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
Collecting pip<10
c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\tmpcdimtd\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:339: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\tmpcdimtd\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:490: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\tmpcdimtd\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:490: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\tmpcdimtd\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:490: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\tmpcdimtd\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:490: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\tmpcdimtd\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:490: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)': /simple/pip/
c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\tmpcdimtd\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py:137: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.python.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '_ssl.c:490: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version'),)) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip<10 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pip<10
```

Obviously, upgrading to newer python defeats my purpose.

The information at the [URL](https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#ssl-py2) recommended for the warning `InsecurePlatformWarning` suggests that I install more things using pip... >.<

**PS** I've tried using easy-install from setuptools-40.0.0 as well, but I could not get this to work. I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly as the setuptools installation documentation has circular links (from the documentation to Pypi, back to the documentation)

Comment: I would use chocolatey to install it. Checkout this link. https://chocolatey.org/packages/python2

Comment: @horatius unfortunately chocolatey packages only go back as far as python 2.7

Comment: Not true. They go all the way back to 2.4.4. https://chocolatey.org/packages/python2/2.6.6

Comment: @horatius oh, this did not show when I used the search for 'python 2.6'. Do the packages include pip do you know? Standard distributions of python 2.6 do not (this is my problem). Im reading the comments about this on that page, they seem mixed at best

Comment: Only one way to find out.

Answer (score 9):

For Python 2.6 you need older `setuptools`. The last setuptools version that works with Python 2.6 is [36.8](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/history.html#v37-0-0).

Download [setuptools-36.8.0.zip](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b8/04/be569e393006fa9a2c10ef72ea33133c2902baa115dd1d4279dae55c3b3b/setuptools-36.8.0.zip), unpack and run `python2.6 setup.py install`.

After that [get-pip.py](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#installing-with-get-pip-py) should install `pip` for you.

The last version of `pip` supporting Python 2.6 is [9.0.3](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#b1-2018-03-31): https://pypi.org/project/pip/9.0.3/#files