# what is the cause of this error when i try to install PIP?

Tags: python, pip

I have downloaded PIP file from some different sources and tried to install it by `python get-pip.py` command for many times.i get this error every time:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "get-pip.py", line 21361, in
<module>
    main()   File "get-pip.py", line 197, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)   File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip._internal   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\tmpe8xyok\pip.zip\pip\_internal\__ini
_.py", line 19, in <module>   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\tmpe8xyok\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3
_init__.py", line 8, in <module>   File "c:\users\asus\appdata\local\temp\tmpe8xyok\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\urllib3
onnectionpool.py", line 92
    _blocking_errnos = {errno.EAGAIN, errno.EWOULDBLOCK}
                                    ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**I'm using python 2.6 on Windows 8**

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. I suspect the `get-pip.py` you have is not for python 2.6. If you have installed python from the `msi` you should have `pip` already. Are you trying to upgrade?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install pip with python 2.6 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560990/how-to-install-pip-with-python-2-6-on-windows)

Comment: That is the set literal syntax and it is not supported in Python 2.6.  It is supported in Python 2.7 though.

Comment: @PedroRodrigues Thank you for trying to help. yes i have installed it from the msi file but i don't have it.i think it installs with python 2.7 and higher.at least that's what i read

Comment: @phd i have installed setuptools but i still get the same error.nothing changed

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister I thought so... so now i have to remove this version and install 2.7 version right?is there any difference in syntax between those tow versions?

Comment: Install from the archive https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c4/44/e6b8056b6c8f2bfd1445cc9990f478930d8e3459e9dbf5b8e2d2922d64d3/pip-9.0.3.tar.gz

Comment: @phd Thanks a lot.