# recieving a syntax error when installing PIP

Tags: python

I have tried to install pip as I don't already have it.

I have tried using `get-pip.py` from `bootstrap.io/2.6/get-pip.py`

I have also tried installing it as a `tar.gz` file, to which I have no idea what to do after downloading the file from the internet.

When I have run:

```
python get-pip.py
```

it always gives the error:

```sh
c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\tmppksvjr\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py: 83: UserWarning: Support for Python 3.0-3.2 has been dropped. Future versions will fail here.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "get-pip.py", line 22123, in <module>
      main()
    File "get-pip.py", line 194, in main
      bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
    File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
      import pip
    File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\tmppksvjr\pip.zip \pip\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\tmppksvjr\pip.zip\pip\vcs\mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\tmppksvjr\pip.zip\pip\download.py", line 37, in <module>
    File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\tmppksvjr\pip.zip\pip\utils\ui.py", line 15, in <module>
    File "c:\users\daniel\appdata\local\temp\tmppksvjr\pip.zip\pip\_vendor\progress\bar.py", line 48
    empty_fill = u'\u2219'
                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I don't mind which way it gets installed as long as I get an up to date version of pip installed.

Comment: Which version of Python are you running?

Comment: Does the `UserWarning: Support for Python 3.0-3.2 has been dropped.` apply?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install pip with python 2.6 on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51560990/how-to-install-pip-with-python-2-6-on-windows)

Comment: First of all, you have a `get-pip.py` for python version 2.6 (bootstrap.io/2.6/get-pip.py) and your python interpreter seems to be version 3.x. It would help to know the python version (call `python --version`) and then you should use `get-pip.py` of matching version.

Comment: @mx0 i have already used that, with no help to progress towards my objective

Comment: @unholysheep 3.2.5

Comment: So you have a version that the `UserWarning` is telling you is no longer supported. You should really upgrade your Python version if possible